# Check Character device

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have character device /dev/nvram and through program I want to check it.
One guy asked to check the st_mode field of the struct stat structure aganist S_ISCHR macro. But I didnt understood this information. Can some one help with some sample programs.

Comment: Read the man page to the `stat()` or `stat64()` system calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main()
{
    struct stat st;

    if (stat("/dev/nvram", &st) != -1)
    {
        if (S_ISCHR(st.st_mode))
        {
            printf("is char device\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```